# How can I replace a character of a item with a specific character in powershell?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, powershell-5.1

I have the an array called $Map that has 29 strings of 23 characters. With the $CharY variable I specify the index of an item and with the $CharX variable I specify which character of that item should be replaced. How do I actually replace this character of the item with the character "0"? I tried using`$Map[$CharY][CharX]` but after running this command, an error is shown saying

```
At line:1 char:1
+ $Map[$CharY][$CharX] = "0"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[.NET strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0), which PowerShell uses, are **immutable**. You can read an individual character by index, but you can't modify it directly. Instead, create a new string with the modified character and assign it back to the array:

```sh
$Map = 1..29 | ForEach-Object { '1' * 23 }
$CharY = 1
$CharX = 2

$Line = $Map[$CharY].ToCharArray()
$Line[$CharX] = '0'
$Map[$CharY] = -join $Line

$Map
```

**Output:**

```text
11111111111111111111111
11011111111111111111111
... [remaining lines omitted] ...
```

**Explanations:**

- The first line fills `$Map` with 29 strings consisting of 23 characters each.
- [`String.ToCharArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray) is used to convert a string into a character array which *can* be modified.
- The unary form of the [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join) operator is used to create a new string from the individual characters. Alternatively the [String constructor that accepts a char array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-string-ctor(system-char())) could be used: `[String]::new($Line)`.